# C# Web Traffic Listener

Tags: c#, sockets, http, proxy, proxy-server

I am trying to write a simple c# console application which shows the accessed websites (sort of proxy server) . I understood that the right approach would be using .Net Sockets and TCP Listeners. However, I tried some code samples and I can get working none of them.
Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Show us your efford and we will show you ours.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler2.com/fiddlercore)

```
public class HttpProxy : IDisposable
{
    public HttpProxy()
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest;
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Startup(8888, true, true);
    }

    void FiddlerApplication_BeforeRequest(Fiddler.Session oSession)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(String.Format("REQ: {0}", oSession.url));
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.Shutdown();
    }
}

static void Main(string[] Args)
{
    var p = new HttpProxy();
    Console.ReadLine();
    p.Dispose();
}
```